# knex - gives me Error: ER_NO_TABLES_USED: No tables used

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am running a mysql db and I am having the following migration, which ran successfully:

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.createTable('posts', function (t) {
        t.increments('id').unsigned().primary();
        t.string('title').notNull();
        t.text('description').nullable();
        t.boolean('deleted').nullable();       
        t.dateTime('createdAt').notNull();
        t.dateTime('updatedAt').nullable();
        t.dateTime('deletedAt').nullable();
    });
};

exports.down = function (knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.dropTable('posts');
};
```

Furthermore I created a seed file:

```
var faker = require('faker');

exports.seed = function (knex, Promise) {
  // Deletes ALL existing entries
  return knex('posts').del()
    .then(function () {
      // Inserts seed entries
      return knex('posts').insert([{
          id: 1,
          title: faker.lorem.sentence,
          description: faker.lorem.paragraph,
          createdAt: faker.date.past,
          updatedAt: faker.date.recent,
          deletedAt: faker.date.recent,
          deleted: faker.random.boolean,

        },
      ]);
    });
};
```

When I run `knex seed:run`, I get the following error:

> Error: ER_NO_TABLES_USED: No tables used
>       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
>       at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
>       at Parser.write (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
>       at Protocol.write (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
>       at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:266:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:253:11)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:211:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:585:20)
>       --------------------
>       at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
>       at Connection.query (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:208:25)
>       at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:152:18
>       at Promise._execute (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:300:9)
>       at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
>       at new Promise (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
>       at Client_MySQL._query (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\knex\lib\dialects\mysql\index.js:146:12)
>       at Client_MySQL.query (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\knex\lib\client.js:197:17)
>       at Runner. (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:146:36)
>       at Runner.tryCatcher (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>       at Runner.query (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\method.js:15:34)
>       at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\knex\lib\runner.js:65:21
>       at tryCatcher (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>       at C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\using.js:185:26
>       at tryCatcher (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
>       at Promise._fulfill (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:638:18)
>       at PromiseArray._resolve (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:126:19)
>       at PromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\learning_crud\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:144:14)

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

missing **()**

title: faker.lorem.sentence(),

description: faker.lorem.paragraph(),

createdAt: faker.date.past(),

updatedAt: faker.date.recent(),

deletedAt: faker.date.recent(),

deleted: faker.random.boolean(),

Comment: You need to explain what you're doing